# Iteration of complex rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I'm studying the book Iterations of Rational Functions by Alan F. Beardon.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WTXZRgUBh0CTGNTMmL-k0xvbyFyHZ5ql/view?usp=sharing) is the page that all the quotations come from.

It is said that:

> If $z$ is close to the fixed point $\zeta$, then, approximately, $|R(z)-\zeta|=|R(z)-R(\zeta)|=|R'(\zeta)|\cdot |z-\zeta|$.

My question is about this affirmation:

> If $z_0$ lies sufficently close to an attraction fixed point $\zeta$, then $z_n \rightarrow \zeta$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

It makes sense that $z_0$ really close to $\zeta$ implies that $|z_0-\zeta|$ is really small but I can't prove that so easy.

These are my thoughts about it:

This equalty $|R(z)-\zeta|=|R(z)-R(\zeta)|=|R'(\zeta)|\cdot |z-\zeta|$ comes from the derivative right?

So for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta>0$ that:
$|z-\zeta|< \delta \implies |R(z)-R(\zeta)|<\epsilon$.

To find the $z_0$ we must consider the "distance" from $z_0$ to $\zeta$ to all $\delta$ ?

But I can't find a way to choose the $z_0$.

Comment: The 1st equality holds since $\zeta$ is assumed to be a fixed point of $R$. The 2nd equality "approximately" holds per the Fundamental Lemma of Differentiation which is I believe why Beardon says "$z_0$ lies sufficiently close". In the case of an attracting fixed point $\zeta=R(\zeta)$, Beardon is basically alluding that if $r>0$ is sufficiently small, then $R$ satisfies the assumptions of the Banach fixed-point theorem on the compact neighborhood $\overline{B(\zeta, r)}$. In other words, $R$ is a contraction on some sufficiently small compact neighborhood of an attracting fixed point $\zeta$.

Comment: Right, thank you

Comment: To be clear: choose $\delta>0$ such that $\eta(z-\zeta)<\frac{1}{2}\left[1-|R'(\zeta)|\right]$ whenever $|z-\zeta|<\delta$, and then use the fact that $c=\frac{1}{2}\left[1+|R'(\zeta)|\right]<1$ is a Lipschitz constant for $R$ on $B(\zeta, \delta)$.

Note: $\eta$ is the function from the fundamental lemma of differentiation.

Comment: Excuse me, for this choice of $\delta$ we merely have that $R$ satisfies the aforementioned Lipschitz condition at $\zeta$ when restricted to $B(\zeta, \delta)$. For a starting point $z \in B(\zeta, \delta)$ the argument that appears in the proof of the Banach fixed-point theorem still applies only instead we end up using the fact that $d(R(u),\zeta)+d(\zeta, R(v))\leq c [d(u,\zeta)+d(\zeta, v)]$. My apologies for the somewhat faulty information. I should say it is helpful to start out assuming $\zeta$ is a fixed-point of $R$.